# Error when using react-i18next: "No overload matches this call" while passing a dynamic key as an argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-i18next

I am using react-i18next for internationalization in my React application. However, when I try to use a dynamic key, I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 12, '(key: TemplateStringsArray | "translation:myapp" | "translation:login" | "translation:forgot_password" | "translation:common" | "translation:validation" | ... 98 more ... | (TemplateStringsArray | ... 102 more ... | "translation:messages.success")[]): string | ... 16 more ... | { ...; }', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | "translation:myapp" | "translation:login" | "translation:forgot_password" | "translation:common" | "translation:validation" | ... 98 more ... | (TemplateStringsArray | ... 102 more ... | "translation:messages.success")[]'.
Overload 2 of 12, '(key: Normalize<{ myapp: string; login: { title: string; welcome: string; description: string; username: string; password: string; "forgot-password": string; "create-account": string; google: string; facebook: string; github: string; }; ... 5 more ...; messages: { ...; }; }> | Normalize<...>[]): string | ... 16 more ... | { ...; }', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Normalize<{ myapp: string; login: { title: string; welcome: string; description: string; username: string; password: string; "forgot-password": string; "create-account": string; google: string; facebook: string; github: string; }; ... 5 more ...; messages: { ...; }; }> | Normalize<...>[]'.
```

Here is the code snippet where the error occurs:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={4} key={item.key}>
  <TextField
    fullWidth
    id={item.key}
    label={t(item.key)} /* here */
    type="text"
    variant="outlined"
    name={item.key}
    defaultValue={params[item.key]}
  />
</Grid>
```

My i18next configuration file for reference:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import translation from './en/translation.json';

export const resources = {
  en: {
    translation
  }
};

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  debug: false,
  resources,
  defaultNS: 'translation',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false
  },
  react: { useSuspense: true },
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
  returnNull: true,
  fallbackLng: 'en'
});

export default i18next;
```

Comment: what is your `item.key` ? And can you try by changing `returnNull` to `false` pls ?

Comment: @lmasneri changing `returnNull` to `false` didn't help. the type of `item.key` is string. e.g. `first_name` or `email`

Comment: @lmasneri if I use this: `const { t }: { t: any } = useTranslation();`, the problem will be sloved but is this safe? I also used [this solution](https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript#type-error-template-literal), but didn't help.

Comment: No don't type `{t: any}` just do `const { t } = useTranslation()`, can you provide your translation.json file pls ?

Comment: @lmasneri this is my translation file:
`{"first_name": "First Name"}`

Comment: can you try doing `en : { translation : { ...translation } }` I don't know if it will solve but it might be this

Comment: @lmasneri didn't work.

Comment: I have the same config on my personal project and this is working...